# How do I increment a string with numbers?

Tags: javascript

I need to increment a value similar to this:

```
A001 becomes A002
A999 becomes B001
B001 becomes B002
etc
Z999 becomes A001
```

I can increment an integer like this:

```
var x = 5;
x++;
```

Yields x = 6

I can increment an character like this:

```
var str = 'A';
str = ((parseInt(str, 36)+1).toString(36)).replace(/0/g,'A').toUpperCase();
if (str =='1A') {
  str = 'A';
}
```

Yields the next character in the alphabet.

This code seems to work, but I'm not sure it's the best way?

```
var str = 'Z999';

if (str == 'Z999') {
   results  = 'A001';
}
else {
  var alpha = str.substring(0,1);
  num = str.substring(1,4);

  if (alpha != 'Z' && num == '999') {
     alpha= ((parseInt(alpha, 36)+1).toString(36)).replace(/0/g,'A').toUpperCase();
  }

  num++;
  var numstr = num + "";
  while (numstr .length < 3) numstr = "0" + numstr ;

  if (numstr == 1000) {
    numstr  = '001';
  }

  results = alpha + numstr;
}
```

*results* seems to give the correct answer. Yes?

Comment: How should an input of over `999` be handled? For instance, what would `A5555` output?

Comment: @JoshCrozier Appear "999" is max for each letter , then to next letter ?

Comment: what happens after `Z999`? `[001`?

Comment: Added code. @JoshCrozier amended results needed above - i.e. Z999 becomes A001 - IOW's it cycles.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `parseInt(input.match(/\d+$/), 10)` to extract the number at the end of the string and `input.match(/^[A-Za-z]/)` to retreive the single character at the beginning.

Increment and pad the number accordingly, and increment the character if the number is over `999` by retrieving the character's character code and incrementing that.

```
String.fromCharCode(letter.charCodeAt(0) + 1);
```

#### Full code/example:

```js
function incrementNumberInString(input) {
  var number = parseInt(input.trim().match(/\d+$/), 10),
      letter = input.trim().match(/^[A-Za-z]/)[0];

  if (number >= 999) {
    number = 1;
    letter = String.fromCharCode(letter.charCodeAt(0) + 1);
    letter = letter === '[' ? 'A': (letter === '{' ? 'a' : letter);
  } else {
    number++;
  }
  
  number = '000'.substring(0, '000'.length - number.toString().length) + number;

  return letter + number.toString();
}

document.querySelector('pre').textContent = 
  'A001: ' + incrementNumberInString('A001')
+ '\nA999: ' + incrementNumberInString('A999')
+ '\nB001: ' + incrementNumberInString('B001')
+ '\nB044: ' + incrementNumberInString('B044')
+ '\nZ999: ' + incrementNumberInString('Z999');
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

#### Output:

> A001: A002
>
> A999: B001
>
> B001: B002
>
> B044: B045
>
> D7777: E001

Comment: I didn't down vote but `A999` does not become `B001` using `incrementNumberInString('A999');` as requested...

Comment: I'm also not the downvoter, but perhaps the downvote is for answering at all; a question that is essentially a problem statement with a request to 'do my work for me' should be downvoted, ignored, and/or closed because it's off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 0):

Try storing `A-Z` in an array , using `String.prototype.replace()` with `RegExp` `/([A-Z])(\d+)/g` to match uppercase characters , digit characters . Not certain what expected result is if `"Z999"` reached ?

```js
var arr = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".split("");

var spans = document.querySelectorAll("span");

function count(el) {

  var data = el.innerHTML.replace(/([A-Z])(\d+)/g, function(match, text, n) {

    var _text, _n;

    if (Number(n) === 999) {
       _text = arr[ arr.indexOf(text) + 1 ];
    } else {
       _text = text
    };
    // `"Z999"` condition ?
    if (_text === undefined) {
        return "<mark>" + text + n + "</mark>"
    }

    _n = Number(n) + 1 < 1000 ? Number(n) + 1 : "001";

    if (n < 10) {
      return _text + n.slice(0, 2) + _n
    };
    
    if (n < 100) {
      return _text + n.slice(0, 1) + _n
    } else {
      return _text + _n
    }
  });
  
  el.innerHTML = data
}

for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
  count(spans[i])
}
```

```html
<span>A001</span>
<span>A999</span>
<span>B001</span>
<span>C999</span>
<span>D123</span>
<span>Z999</span>
```